# How to raise an error if a url was accessed but not registered in python-responses?

Tags: python, python-responses

By default, Responses will raise an assertion error if a url was registered but not accessed. How can one do the opposite i.e. raise an error if a url was accessed but not registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request a URL that was not registered, you will get a

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
```

**Example**

```
import responses
import requests

@responses.activate
def test_my_api():
    resp = requests.get('https://twitter.com/')
    print resp

def run_my_api():
    resp = requests.get('https://twitter.com/')
    print resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Without responses..."
    run_my_api()
    print ""
    print "With responses..."
    test_my_api()
```

**Output**

```
Without responses...
<Response [200]>

With responses...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 18, in <module>
    test_my_api()
  File "<string>", line 3, in wrapper
  File "example.py", line 6, in test_my_api
    resp = requests.get('https://twitter.com/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/responses.py", line 294, in unbound_on_send
    return self._on_request(adapter, request, *a, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/responses.py", line 239, in _on_request
    raise response
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused: GET https://twitter.com/
```

The `<Response [200]>` is from the undecorated `run_my_api` call. You can use `assertRaises` or the equivalent to check for the exception.